# duplicate method in javap result

Tags: java, generics, javap

There is a method in BaseController, e.g.

```
public abstract class BaseManagementController<V, F extends BaseForm> {

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    protected void add(@Valid @RequestBody F form, HttpServletRequest request) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and a concrete Controller extends it and override add method

```
public class BannerController extends BaseManagementController<BannerVO, BannerForm> {
    @Override
    public void add(@Valid @RequestBody BannerForm form, HttpServletRequest request) {
        super.add(form, request);
    }
}
```

when I `javap` BannerController I see two add method

```
 public void add(com.foo.admin.web.vo.BannerForm, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest);
    descriptor: (Lcom/foo/admin/web/vo/BannerForm;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC


  public void add(com.foo.admin.web.vo.BaseForm, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest);
    descriptor: (Lcom/foo/admin/web/vo/BaseForm;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_BRIDGE, ACC_SYNTHETIC
```

why have two add method? Is it overload?

Answer (score 0):

> „*why have two add method?*“

Because there could be some functionality that might be more *generally-applicable* to all *`Controllers`*. And that general functionality could be implemented in *`BaseManagementController.add()`*…

```
public abstract class BaseManagementController<V, F extends BaseForm> {

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    protected void add(@Valid @RequestBody F form, HttpServletRequest request) {
        /* ...All Controllers need to do this... */
        controlStuff(form, request);
    }

    private void controlStuff(F form, HttpServletRequest request) {
        /* ...do whatever Controllers do...*/
    }
}
```

Then your more *specialized* implementations like *`BannerController.add()`* could do something banner-related only…

```
public class BannerController extends BaseManagementController<BannerVO, BannerForm> {

    @Override
    public void add(@Valid @RequestBody BannerForm form, HttpServletRequest request) {
        super.add(form, request);
        processBanner(form, request);
    }

    private void processBanner(BannerForm form, HttpServletRequest request) {
        /*...do something special for banners...*/
    }
}
```

The subclass's *`add()`* could simply call *`super.add()`* and piggyback off of existing functionality in its super's implementation.

> „*Is it overload?*“

No. But it is [*overridden*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1)…

> …
>
> *An instance method `mC` declared in or inherited by class C *overrides from C* another method `mA` declared in class A, iff all of the following are true:*
>
> - *C is a subclass of A*.
> - *C does not inherit `mA`*.
> - *The signature of m<sub>C</sub> is a
>   subsignature ([§8.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2)) of the signature of `mA`*.
> - *One of the following is
>   true*:
>
>   - *`mA` is public*.
>   - ...